# ngrx state- when to flatten state?

Tags: angular, ngrx, flatten, ngrx-store, ngrx-entity

There are strong recommendations to flatten out the state tree for an ngrx store, and I've worked to do so throughout my app.  I understand with, and agree with the reasons behind doing so- flat state trees are easier to manage, deep copy, etc.

However, I've run into a scenario that leaves me wondering the most maintainable way of setting up my state tree.  I have a feature, `Crews` which contains a number of users on a Crew.  An instance of a crew can have substitute users (e.g.- if someone on that crew is unavailable).  A `sub` simply defines the original user ID, and the replacement user ID.  As far as I can tell, there are two ways I can do this.  The most straightforward way would be to have a non-flat structure- something that might look like this:

```
export interface User {
  id: string;
  username: string;
}

export interface Crew {
  id: string;
  members: string[];         //User IDs
  subs: [string, string][];  //[Orig UID, Sub UID]
}

export interface UserState extends EntityState<User> { }
export interface CrewState extends EntityState<Crew> { }

export interface AppState {
    users: UserState;
    crews: CrewState;
}
```

The other option, is to create a `Subs` feature, and the subs within `Crew` would point to an id in subs:

```
export interface User {
  id: string;
  username: string;
}

export interface Crew {
  id: string;
  members: string[];        //User IDs
  subs: string[];           //Sub ID
}

export interface Sub {
  id: string;
  original: string;         //Original UID
  sub: string;              //Sub UID
}

// Using ngrx entities
export interface UserState extends EntityState<User> { }
export interface CrewState extends EntityState<Crew> { }
export interface SubState extends EntityState<Sub> { }

export interface AppState {
    users: UserState;
    subs: SubState;
    crews: CrewState;
}
```

But this seems a bit overkill to me- creating an entire new feature, simply to represent two string ID values.  Any thought on which direction would be most maintainable/straightforward, or a better way to represent this?

Comment: I think you're overkilling it. Things should be balanced, said Thanos.